# Lossless, dependency preserving BCNF

Tags: database, dependencies, lossless

The following relations are given:

R1 = {A, B, C}

R2 = {C, D}

R3 = {D, E}

The task is to find a set of function dependencies to satisfy BCNF (lossless, and dependency preserving). I think that this is not possible here.

Without dependency preserving i got this:

A -> B, C

C -> A, D

D -> A, E

Is this correct and is it possible to find a dep. pres. set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dependencies do you need to preserve?

Comment: You haven't listed any functional dependencies in the *problem*. In R1, you *might* have the FD A->BC, or AB->C, or B->AC, etc. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The problem is, that I must specify a set of functional dependencies, that the set of relations R1-R3 is in BCNF (lossless and functional dependency preserving) and give suitable keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. But the simplest way to "manufacture" a relation in BCNF is to use one and only one single-attribute key. These functional dependencies

- A->BC
- C->D
- D->E

result in these relations.

- R<sub>a</sub> {**A** BC}
- R<sub>b</sub> {**C** D}
- R<sub>c</sub> {**D** E}

R<sub>a</sub> is in 5NF. The other two are in 6NF.

Comment: Okay, seems clear. But what do I do, if I have the same resulting relations and I have to specify functional dependencies that R1-R3 are in 3. NF, but not in BCNF?

Comment: You have to determine an FD where the left-hand side is not a candidate key. Informally, when a relation is in BCNF, "the only arrows in the FD diagram are arrows out of candidate keys." (Date, *An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7ed, p367)